# Using $resource and creating a POST request?

Tags: angularjs, api, post, request, angular-resource

I've been digging at this but cannot figure this one out, here's the simple attempt I've made, I thought this was fine but it seems to still request as get....

```
this.request = function(url, requestData) {
    return $resource(url, null, {
        post : {
            method : 'POST',
            params : requestData || {}
        }
    });
};
```

Using it:

```
this.request('/some/api/url', {data : true}).post();
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get back a promise object so that I can use the repsonse data....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create your resource like so:

```
$resource(url, null, {
    post: {
        method: 'POST'
    }
});
```

And then:

```
this.request.post(
    requestData,
    function (successResponse) {
        // Do whatever with response
    },
    function (failResponse) {
        // Do whatever with response
    }
);
```

This will send a POST request to `url` with `requestData` as the body.

Comment: I did see the save method, however I felt it was a bit backwards, say we have an api call to get users by id, so the url would be something like

`/users/1123123`

And then the request would be something like `this.request('/users/123123').save({}, function() {

});`

Comment: I just didn't want to have to call a save method which makes no sense when technically I'm getting data with a post method

Comment: I've updated my answer so that you can use `.post()` to post.

Comment: Using this exact same solution it's still requesting with GET.. gahhh

Comment: I've just tried using the default save as well and that also is only using GET....

Comment: You're just calling `this.request.post()` and not `this.request('/whatever').post()`, correct? EDIT: Nvm, that isn't even a performable action. How are you verifying that it's still sending a GET?

Comment: I'm getting a error back from the server in the chrome console, giving me a 404 and the request type in the headers

Comment: How very odd. I'm testing it myself (`$resource('something',null,{post:{method: 'POST'},}).post()`) and it's (correctly) sending a POST and receiving a 404.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I can't solve it either, I've just tried the same thing in jsfiddle and It's make a post request, it must be something on the server that's intercepting the request, I really don't know. http://jsfiddle.net/3PUxx/143/